# Require JS with parameter

Tags: require

I am new to ReqireJs. I am trying to do the following:

I have a file(mymodule.js) with the following code:

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    var name;
    $(document).ready(function() {
       //do some load stuff
    });
});
```

I am trying to include the file into some other file as follows:

```
require(['modules/mymodule.js']);
```

which works fine. My question is that how can I pass some parameters from require(['modules/mymodule.js']); into mymodules.js?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the solution here:

http://blog.novanet.no/4-strategies-for-passing-parameters-to-requirejs-modules/

I have used the code from 1st step from above link "Passing parameter to method" as follows:

```
define(
    [
        'jquery'
    ], 
    function($){
        return {
            sayHello: function(name){
                alert("Hello " + name);
            }
        };
    }
);
```

Then I have passed the parameter as follows:

```
require(['modules/mymodule.js'], function(mymodule){
    mymodule.sayHello("World");
});
```